# MS Project Calculating Finish Dates by Number of days from End Date

Tags: microsoft-project, scheduling

I am building out a timeline in MS Project where I need to work backwards from the end date. I am able to change the project settings to Schedule from Finish Date. I also have a task set for the completion date with that end date set.

I am now looking to build my tasks to have the finish dates be a specific number of days from the Project Finish Date. For example: I would like "Task #10: Website Go Live" be 10 days from the Project Finish Date. I can do this manually of course but every task is going to be built this way and I want to be able to change my Project Finish Date for future projects and all my tasks to update accordingly.